Check that contents of a `tl` consist of a valid csname and not a command or blank
I have content stored in a token list as \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{bfseries}. I need to have the input as a csname not a cmd \bfseries. As the input is expected to come from users through key-value settings, I need to check 1) that is not empty, b) is a csname for a command that exists and  c) lastly is NOT in the form of \cmd. The first 2 checks I managed, but I need some help for the last one. I tried token_is_macro but got into all sort of problems:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_yl_yl_tmpa_tl
\bool_new:N \yl_if_valid_cs_input_bool


%\cs_new:Npn \my_command_format:{my command output}

% Need to check that user input #1 stored in a var tl  is:
%   1) a valid cs
%   2) not empty
%   3) not a command 
%   i.e bfseries and not \bfseries and not empty
%   

\cs_set:Npn \__yl_input_is_empty:N #1
{
  
  \tl_if_empty:VTF #1 {
  You need to specify a formatter name. I will ignore and use
  the default formatter.
  }{\typeout{not blank accepted}} 
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yl_if_input_cs:n #1
{ 

  \cs_if_exist:cTF{#1}
    {\bool_set_true:N\yl_if_valid_cs_input_bool  }
    { \bool_set_false:N \yl_if_valid_cs_input_bool }
  
  
  
  \bool_if:NT\yl_if_valid_cs_input_bool
  { \use:c{#1} }
  

}

% Main function
\cs_set:Npn \__yl_validate_and_use_input:N #1{
  \__yl_input_is_empty:N{#1} 
  \__yl_if_input_cs:n{\tl_use:N#1}
  }


%%============== test

\tl_set:Nn\l_yl_tmpa_tl{Huge}

\__yl_validate_and_use_input:N \l_yl_tmpa_tl

testing 

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


Why does it need to come as a csname? You can pass \bfseries as a value to a key just fine. Can't you just use the \ stripper on the value? As far as I remember it does nothing unless the macro starts with \.

I'm not sure that your test conditions make much sense. You will accept input like section and hbox and your code will explode ...

@UlrikeFischer  Thanks not in the context I am using it, as valid input is also in a clist so I am doing further tests.

I would test that

The token list is not empty
That a control sequence equal to \<detokenized-content> exists

as that seems to cover your use case. Thus
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__yl_if_valid:N #1 { T , F , TF }
  {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { ! \tl_if_blank_p:V #1 }
      { \cs_if_exist_p:c { \tl_to_str:N #1 } }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }

This would be used for example
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { bar }
\__yl_if_valid:NTF \l_tmpa_tl \TRUE \FALSE
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \bar }
\__yl_if_valid:NTF \l_tmpa_tl \TRUE \FALSE
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { bong }
\__yl_if_valid:NTF \l_tmpa_tl \TRUE \FALSE


Seems you missed the #1 at the first line, when I fix and do \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{bfseries}  \__yl_if_valid:NTF\l_tmpa_tl{T}{F} I get undefined \bool_lazy_and:TF` I am using texlive2024, is this recent?

I would appreciate it also if you show usage.

@yannisl Corrected with a demo

Thanks very much, works nicely.

Border case: If the escape char is negative this might lead to false-positives.

One could make the tests more careful, but personally I'd be looking at the input syntax ...

@Skillmon you mean the !?

@cfr no, if for instance you do \escapechar=-1 \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \! } \__yl_if_valid:NTF the solution here yields true though it should be false. The boolean logic is fine, it just doesn't cover all the edge cases. (which admittedly isn't possible to do expandable, though the edge case I mentioned would be possible to expandably detect)

I'd define a conditional.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \yl_if_valid_csname:n {p,T,F,TF}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}
   {% blank
    \prg_return_false:
   }
   {% not blank
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n {#1} } { \token_if_cs_p:N #1 }
     {% it's of the form \cmd
      \prg_return_false:
     }
     {% check if the csname exists
      \cs_if_exist:cTF {\tl_to_str:n {#1}}
       {% the csname exists
        \prg_return_true:
       }
       {% the csname doesn't exist
        \prg_return_false:
       }
     }
   }
 }

% let's test

\NewDocumentCommand{\testvalidcsname}{m}
 {
  \tl_to_str:n{#1}~is~
  \yl_if_valid_csname:nTF {#1} {VALID} {INVALID}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\testvalidcsname{bfseries}

\testvalidcsname{a}

\testvalidcsname{zzzz}

\testvalidcsname{\bfseries}

\testvalidcsname{\bfseries\ttfamily}

\testvalidcsname{bfseries\ttfamily}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[2][]{...}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\1}[2][]{...}

\testvalidcsname{\foo}

\testvalidcsname{\1}

\end{document}



Appreciate your help, very neat and professional code. I accepted Joseph's as he responded earlier.
